# count duplicated rows, by unique row

Tags: r, data.table

I think this pretty straightforward problam has a very simple solution, but I can't figure it out.

Lets say I've got a data.table with some duplicated rows (rows 3 and 4 are identical)

```
dt <- data.table( val1 = c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6), val2 = 8 )             
#    val1 val2
# 1:    1    8
# 2:    2    8
# 3:    3    8
# 4:    3    8
# 5:    4    8
# 6:    5    8
# 7:    6    8
```

I want to throw away the duplucated rows, keeping only unique rows,  and introduce a new column `val3` that indicates how often a row occurs in the original data

expected output:

```
dt.output <- data.table( val1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), val2 = 8, val3 = c(1,1,2,1,1,1) )             
#    val1 val2 val3
# 1:    1    8    1
# 2:    2    8    1
# 3:    3    8    2
# 4:    4    8    1
# 5:    5    8    1
# 6:    6    8    1
```

I've got the feeling I'm almost there using an update-join with `unique(dt)[, val3 := ....]`, but I can't get the `...` part to return what I want and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
dt[, .(val3 = .N), by = .(val1, val2)]
```

Or continuing with your first approach one could do something like the following:

```
unique(dt)[, val3 := dt[.SD, on = .(val1, val2), .N, by = .EACHI][, N]][]
```

Note that one can use a character vector also in `by`:

```
byvars <- grep("val\\d+", names(dt), value = TRUE)
dt[, .(val3 = .N), by = byvars]
```

Comment: <slaps palm to face>.. of course.. thanks.. and what If i've got a large nuber of columns `val1, val2, ..., valn` and do not want to type all of them by hand into the `by = `

Comment: @Wimpel :), you can use character vector in by (that you can produce with some system)... see update.

Comment: There might be several ways to dot this. This is an alternative:  `dt %>% group_by(val1, val2) %>% summarize(var1 = val1[1], var2=val2[1])`